# Font color won't change on hover

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, colors

I have this login button which looks like this:

[image]

Now when I hover on it, it would look like this:

[image]

I can't make the text white when I hover on it

My code:

```css
.button {
    border: 0px solid #011f4b;
    background: #011f4b;
    padding: 3px 21px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Questrial;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
   
   .button:hover {
    border: 0px solid #1292e1;
    background: #1292e1;
    color: white;
    }
   
   .button:active {
    background: #1292e1;
    color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<a href='#' class='button'>Login</a>
```

Comment: you put both color to white

Comment: @TemaniAfif What do you mean?

Comment: i mean that you put white and it's white ... where is the issue in your code ?

Comment: With your current CSS the text is always white.

Comment: @stybl yeah text should always be white, but when I hover on it, it changes

Comment: Can you edit the snippet to reproduce that? It seems to be working properly here

Comment: i tihnk you copied only a part of a big CSS code ... am sure there is some other CSS that creating your issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif not really, I used button generator and that was only the css generated

Comment: yes but am sure you are using this CSS in a site right ? so there is more CSS on this site

Comment: @stybl I used button generator, on the website where I made it, it works fine. Not sure why it is like that

Comment: try the code of my answer to see if i am right or not

Comment: @TemaniAfif didn't work sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the **a** tag in your selector to avoid having conlict with other CSS you may have in your site :

```css
a.button {
  border: 0px solid #011f4b;
  background: #011f4b;
  padding: 3px 21px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Questrial;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

a.button:hover {
  border: 0px solid #1292e1;
  background: #1292e1;
  color: white;
}

a.button:active {
  background: #1292e1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href='#' class='button'>Login</a>
```

you may also consider the **!important** to force keeping the white color like this :

```
a.button:hover {
      border: 0px solid #1292e1;
      background: #1292e1;
      color: white!important;
    }
```

Comment: you  may consider to add **!important** in the hover part

Comment: Post it as an answer i'll check you up

Answer (score 3):

Try to add ! `!important` that will force the color to white if there is another css code that set the color on hover to another one